# Issues with loading XLConnect library in R

Tags: r, package

I have installed XLConnect package though my R studio. When I try to load the library I get the following error

```
> library(XLConnect)
Loading required package: XLConnectJars
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘XLConnectJars’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package ‘XLConnectJars’ could not be loaded
```

I checked the `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library` folder and I am noticed all three mentioned libraries(`XLConnect`, `XLConnectJars`, `rJava`) already present.

Comment: do you have the correct java version corresponding to the r version you are using. they both should be 32 or 64 bit

Comment: are you reading excel file into R?You can even try readxl package. The readxl package makes it easy to get data out of Excel and into R.

Comment: Yes. Both R and Java are 64 bit versions.